# Install GitHub hosted packages in Spacemacs

Tags: github, emacs, webkit, haxe

I have been using vim for a while now and decided to try Emacs. I picked Spacemacs since it's easier for a vim user to transition to.

I was able to create a package layer to install packages hosted in MELPA but when I tried installing packages hosted on GitHub using `:fetcher github` it gave an error: 'Package [package name] is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?'

A few packages I tried are [Emacs Webkit](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-emacs/tree/master/site-lisp/extensions/webkit) and [haxe-complete](https://github.com/aharrison/haxe-complete)

How do I install packages hosted on GitHub?

Edit: I forgot to mention I've checked out the develop branch.

Comment: This feature is available only in the develop branch currently.

Comment: @syl20bnr Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using the develop branch.

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/5f756be832841268dc70e1cc54c4ac860b0eccdf/spacemacs/packages.el#L45

Comment: @syl20bnr Thank you. I will try it right now and report back asap.

Comment: @syl20bnr I realised that I have already tried something similar and it didn't work. I tried it again just now as well.

Comment: Open an issue on the github repo, there is a bug then.

Comment: @syl20bnr I'm currently reinstalling the develop branch of Spacemacs. If that fails then I'll open an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @syl20bnr Reinstalling Spacemacs didn't help. Opening an issue.